# Why native function written in objective C is is not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, objective-c, react-native, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to get output from native function to use in frontend, here is the function,

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getActiveAudioDevice:
                 resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  MediaDevice * _Nullable  devices = [meetingSession.audioVideo getActiveAudioDevice];
  NSLog(@"Hello Devices: %@", devices);
  
  if (!devices) {
    reject(@"event_failure", @"failed to list audio devices", nil);
  } else {
    resolve(devices);
  }

}
```

I am triggering it in JS like this ,

```
const selectedAudioDevice = useCallback(async() => { 

       const activeDevice= await NativeFunction.selectedDevice("")
       setActiveDevice(activeDevice) }
```

When I trigger this from frontend I can see in logs that Native function is returning a device but in JS all I get is undefined, any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you post a bit more context? maybe the full Objective-C file? There are also some inconsistencies: the method called in the JS side does not have the same name than the method defined in Objective-C and it seems like the Objective-C definition of the method is missing the first parameter

Comment: Unfortunately can not post code here, and the method name is different because I have defined that method with a different name in bridge.js . Which parameter is missing in objective-c ? I am a newbie to this language

Comment: ```
 RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getActiveAudioDevice:
                 resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject
 ```
 should be something like:
 ```
 RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getActiveAudioDevice: NSString* parameter
                 resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject
 ```
to fit the call as you are passing a string on `NativeFunction.selectedDevice("")`

Comment: Other than that it is a bit difficult to help more without more context as it might depend on the setup of the bridge, etc ... If you can not publish more code a minimal reproduction could be helpful too

Comment: Let me try this one you suggested and see what I can do for reproduction , thank you !!

Comment: Hey it finally worked, ios apps does not take MediaDevices as arguments, 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types

Had to convert that into a string and then it worked.